# Binding a control to xaml provided by domain object

Tags: wpf

We have an area of our UI that we want to be controlled by the user. Basically they provide us a piece of xaml that defines how the particular area should look.

```
public class Project
{
  public string DisplaySpecificationXml { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way to bind the property from the domain object that happens to know the xaml so that we can see it at runtime;

PS - Note that the viewed project will change at runtime and I need to update those areas of the UI then.

Comment: I sure hope you trust your users implicitly: with a bit of cleverness, one could craft xaml with some absolutely horrid results...

Comment: This isn't an app for external consumption, line of business app. And the users who will define for custom areas are actually developers for the business. There isn't a huge security risk here, but thanks for the note it is important, and worth an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.RuntimeXAML"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples"
        Title="RuntimeXAML" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:stringToUIConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" x:Name="Lst"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem.DisplaySpecificationXml, ElementName=Lst, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public partial class RuntimeXAML : Window
    {
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; } 

        public RuntimeXAML()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Projects = new List<Project>
                           {
                               new Project()
                                   {
                                       DisplaySpecificationXml = 
                                        "<StackPanel>" + 
                                        "<TextBlock FontWeight='Bold' Text='This is UserControl1'/>" + 
                                        "<ComboBox Text='ComboBox'/>" + 
                                        "</StackPanel>"
                                   },
                               new Project()
                                   {

                                   }
                           };
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

Converter:

```
 public class stringToUIConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || (!(value is string)))
                return null;

            var header = "<Grid xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' " + 
                         "xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>";

            var footer = "</Grid>";

            var xaml = header + (string) value + footer;

            var UI = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as UIElement;
            return UI;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks good on first pass. I will double check it tonight, and accept as soon as I see it.